# AMPscript required. Show nothing if a field is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've attempted to use the following AMPscript to show nothing if a field contains no value.
It is erroring, no doubt because there is an obvious syntax error somewhere, but I cannot see where.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
%%=iif(empty(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c),"",Scholarship Title:%%Variable_Scholarship_Name__c%% 

Scholarship Amount: $%%=FormatNumber(AttributeValue("Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c"),"#,###")=%%
=%%
```

If the field is not empty, I need the email to display as follows:

Scholarship Title: Genius

Scholarship Amount: $20

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to lookup those values from somewhere and judging by the `__c`, those come from Salesforce, so you either need to point from which object in Salesforce or which Synchronized DE they should come from.

Using the [iif](https://ampscript.guide/iif/) function for this use case would be too complicated, so it's better to use an AMPscript block wit an [if/else](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript201.htm) statement:

```
%%[
SET @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
"ObjectName",
"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c,Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c", 
"Id" = "SubscriberID")

SET @row = row(@rows,1)
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c")
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c")


IF NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) THEN
]%%

Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%

Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c)=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Above will pull data directly from Salesforce, so only use it on CloudPages. You will need to replace "**ObjectName**" and "**SubscriberID**" in the above to point it to the right object and enable to identify the record correctly.

If you need this for an email, it's better to use Synchronized Data Extensions:

```
%%[
SET @rows = LookupRows("NameOfSynchedDE","Id", "Id")

SET @row = row(@rows,1)
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c")
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c")


IF NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) THEN
]%%

Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%

Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c)=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Here you will need to replace "**NameOfSynchedDE**" with the name of your Data Extension, first "**Id**" with the Id column in that DE and the second "**Id**" with the Id to identify the correct record.

So, if for example, this data comes from the `Contact_Salesforce` synchronized data extension, the final code would look something like this:

```
%%[
SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey)

SET @row = row(@rows,1)
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c")
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c")


IF NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) THEN
]%%

Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%

Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c)=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped

Comment: Actually, one further question if I may.

How can I get the Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c to display as X,XXX?  So if it's $1000 I'd want it to display as $1,000.

Comment: @ThomasHockey see here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66224/ampscript-to-format-number-field

Comment: Thank you, that worked